# Bold is too Bold in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've testing this in this in Safari and it works fine, but when using Chrome or Firefox the bold is way to bold. Here is a sample chunk of code I'm using:
HTML:

```
<ul>
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="2">
    <li>
      <span>
        Cooly Guy
      </span>
      - 
      <span class="i">
        Human
      </span>
      <br>
      robot, alien, adi, 
      <br>
      yolo, fa 
      <br>
      youtube.com/yt.ID
    </font>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#Users span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#Users2 span {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#Users ul span.i {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Safari on left, Chrome in center and Firefox on right: http://gyazo.com/219ff996619292b089d2b0866bb4a553

As you can see Chrome's and Firefox's bold text looks 'fuzzy' compared to Safari.

Comment: I'm not sure why this has received a down vote and the other answer has received 3 up votes. The other answer is still giving me fuzzy bold text on other browsers than Safari

Answer (score 5):

try giving numeric values instead of `bold`

```
#Users span{
    font-weight: 600;
}
#Users2 span{
    font-weight: 500;
}

#Users ul span.i{
    font-style: italic;

}
```

You can set the values from `100` to `900`

```
100 : thin
200 : extra-light
300 : light
400 : normal
500 : medium
600 : semi-bold
700 : bold
800 : extra-bold
900 : ultra bold
```

Comment: Be careful with this, not all the fonts are equal: http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Raleway

Comment: Didn't work, Here  is an example screenshot: http://gyazo.com/e77827053d30278e7c6268e3e920cbef - Left side is Safari, right side is Chrome. This is a comparison of the Bold text